# Update Column Based On Select Query

Tags: mysql

I want to sequentially add track numbers to music in a database. I have a select query that does this. But it creates a new column.

Is it possible to update an existing field (`TrackNum`, which currently has garbage data) instead, using the select query as part of the update?

Here is the current query, which adds a new column `RowNumber` to the output. But I want to be updating `TrackNum` instead.

```
select @n := @n + 1 RowNumber, t.*
from (select @n:=0) initvars, tablename t
WHERE concat(Author, ' - ', Name) = 'Mickey Mouse - Disneyland'
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:
`update table2 t, (select @n:=0) initvars
set t.num = (@n := @n + 1)`

Comment: I assume I can just ass the where clause on the end?

Comment: yes, add ...WHERE concat(Author, ' - ', Name) = 'Mickey Mouse - Disneyland'